Balancing Magic Numbers and Readability in C++ Code
I have written a C++ program that calculates the floor of 64 divided by n for values of n from 1 to 64. I'm trying to get a faster SWAR algorithm that avoids costly divisions.
The problem is that the SWAR method uses a lot of magic numbers.
I used constexpr functions to show the origin of the magic numbers, but the code has become long and unreadable.
Is it possible to find a middle ground where the code is both concise and readable? Or should I leave the long constexpr code?
Here is my code:
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

// Function floor(64/n)=⌊64/n⌋, for 0<n<65
//      n=64,63,⋯,33,32,⋯,22,21,⋯,17,16,⋯,13,12,11,10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
//  ⌊64/n⌋= 1, 1,⋯, 1, 2,⋯, 2, 3,⋯, 3, 4,⋯, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,12,16,21,32,64
//                                      ⌊64/n⌋=64_
//                                ⌊64/n⌋=32____
//                                   ⋯⋯⋯
//                         ⌊64/n⌋=4___
//                 ⌊64/n⌋=3________
//        ⌊64/n⌋=2________
// ⌊64/n⌋=1_______
//       64,⋯,33,32,⋯,22,21,⋯,17,16,⋯3,2,⋯,2,1

// Function to compute ⌊64/n⌋ for 0 < n < 65
constexpr uint8_t floor64OverN(uint8_t n)
{
    return static_cast<uint8_t>(64u / n);
}

// Function to generate an array of ⌊64/n⌋ values for n from 1 to 64
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 65> generateResultArray()
{
    std::array<uint8_t, 65> result = {};
    for (uint8_t i = 1; i <= 64; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = floor64OverN(i);
    }
    return result;
}

// Precomputed array of ⌊64/n⌋ values for n from 1 to 64
constexpr std::array<uint8_t, 65> RESULT_TO_GENERATE = generateResultArray();

// Union to allow access to a 64-bit integer as an array of 8-bit integers
union Union64_8
{
    uint64_t as_uint64;
    std::array<uint8_t, 8> as_array_uint8;
};

// Function to generate an array of indices n, where the value of ⌊64/n⌋ changes
constexpr Union64_8 jumpsBy1()
{
    Union64_8 jumps = {0};
    jumps.as_array_uint8 = {};
    uint8_t idx = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 8; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        if (RESULT_TO_GENERATE[i] > RESULT_TO_GENERATE[i + 1])
        {
            jumps.as_array_uint8[idx++] = i;
        }
    }
    jumps.as_array_uint8[idx] = 65u;

    return jumps;
}

// Precomputed array of indices where the value of ⌊64/n⌋ changes
constexpr Union64_8 JUMPS_BY_1 = jumpsBy1();

// Multiplicator array initialized to all ones.
// By multiplying with an 8 bit uint, makes 8 copies bitshifted.
constexpr Union64_8 MULTIPLICATOR = {.as_array_uint8 = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}};

// This array of compare flags is initialized with each element set to 0b10000000 (128 in decimal)
// It is used to flag the bits that change during multiple SWAR  comparison operations x<y
constexpr Union64_8 COMPARE_FLAGS = {.as_array_uint8 = {{128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128}}};

// Precomputed table for ⌊64/n⌋ values for n from 1 to 7
constexpr Union64_8 TABLE_N1_N7 = {.as_array_uint8 = {{0, floor64OverN(1), floor64OverN(2), floor64OverN(3), floor64OverN(4), floor64OverN(5), floor64OverN(6), floor64OverN(7)}}};

// Function to compute ⌊64/n⌋ using SWAR technique
uint8_t SWARfloor64OverN(uint8_t n)
{
    if (n < 8)
    {
        // For n < 8, use the precomputed table
        return (TABLE_N1_N7.as_uint64 >> (8 * n)) & 255ULL;
    }
    // For n >= 8, use the SWAR technique
    uint64_t substraction = (JUMPS_BY_1.as_uint64 | COMPARE_FLAGS.as_uint64) - n * MULTIPLICATOR.as_uint64;
    uint8_t result = __builtin_popcountll(substraction & COMPARE_FLAGS.as_uint64);
    return result;
};

int main()
{
    // Print the precomputed array of ⌊64/n⌋ values
    std::cout << "generateResultArray: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 65; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(RESULT_TO_GENERATE[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Print the array of indices where the value of ⌊64/n⌋ changes
    std::cout << "JUMPS_BY_128: ";
    for (auto jump : JUMPS_BY_1.as_array_uint8)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(jump) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Print the array of indices as a 64-bit integer
    std::cout << "JUMPS_BY_1 as uint64_t: " << JUMPS_BY_1.as_uint64 << std::endl;

    // Print the results of ⌊64/n⌋ for n from 1 to 64
    for (uint8_t n = 1; n <= 64; ++n)
    {
        uint8_t result = SWARfloor64OverN(n);
        std::cout << "n = " << static_cast<int>(n) << ", ⌊64/n⌋ = " << static_cast<int>(result) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Using a union for type punning is not legal in C++.

Is it worth it?
Sure, divisions are one of the more expensive CPU instructions, but you are replacing it with a function call that has a conditional, multiplication, subtraction and several bitwise operations, each of which are cheap on their own, but they have dependencies on each other, and the latencies add up. You are using more registers and execution ports, so depending on the other code you program will be executing, you might not actually gain that much.
Also, if you are doing a lot of 64 / n calculations, wouldn't it be better to do real SIMD and calculate many divisions in parallel?
If @PeterCordes is watching this post, I'm sure he will be able to tell what the best way to do this is (in general). Also, you should benchmark realistic code to see what is actually faster for your specific use case.
Correct way to cast array to integer
As indi mentioned, type punning a union is a no-no in C++. If you do this, the compiler might generate incorrect code. Use std::bit_cast() instead to convert from an array of 8 bytes to a 64-bit integer.
Don't use all-capital names
In most common code styles, all-capital names are reserved for macros only, or perhaps sometimes also for the names of enum values. However, constants should not be all-caps.
Use std::print()
Since you tagged the post c++23, consider using std::print() and friends to print results. For example:
for (uint8_t n = 1; n <= 64; ++n)
{
    std::println("n = {},  ⌊64/n⌋ = {}", n, SWARfloor64OverN(n));
}


I wrote more than a dozen different solutions and managed to halve the time used by floor(64/n). I'm not sure that this is the best one. I do not intend to use this as a called function (it will be inlined). Additionally, I want to avoid using the L1 cache (such as reading the answer from an array) because this function is used frequently, and I want to prevent side effects like erasing the L1 cache. However, microbenchmarking it is challenging.
My question is about using constexpr, as my current alternatives are filled with magic numbers.

This function has a conditional, because the benchmarks get faster than when doing branchless code. I have no clue why. Maybe the benchmark code is too short for the CPU to bet the house on the wrong branch, and it will work very different when inlined in real code. The problem is that uint64 is too short to solve the entire array with a single method, so I need to split it in 2, and that leads to conditionals and problems doing it branchless.

Also, if you are doing a lot of 64 / n calculations, wouldn't it be better to do real SIMD and calculate many divisions in parallel? - yes, by parallelizing a bithack.  Or writing a scalar bithack like this and letting the compiler auto-vectorize loops that use it, especially on AArch64 where SIMD popcount is widely available.  x86 at least doesn't have SIMD integer division, although it does have SIMD FP division.  AArch64 NEON doesn't have integer division either.  Apparently SVE has u32 division, but not u8 or u16:  https://godbolt.org/z/4nEEjcdWP

@PeterCordes You can do SIMD widen u8 to u32, conversion to float, division, conversion to integer and then narrow to u8 again. Sounds expensive, but it might pipeline well?

Yes, that's what Clang is doing in my Godbolt link.  I just added the OP's code (https://godbolt.org/z/rsc6K1E8E); I hadn't realized how many instructions it would be.  A lot of it is setting up constants which would hoist out of loops, and scalar popcount on ARM goes to SIMD regs and back.  I haven't fully read the OP's code; if it needs a 64-bit SIMD element for each 8-bit input, that's not great for vectorization.
On very new CPUs that have SVE available, just widening to 32-bit for HW division might be better than widening to 64-bit for this bithack.

You are using more registers Yes.   and execution ports - maybe not.  On Intel before Ice Lake, 8-bit div is 10 uops (https://uops.info/), so hardware division isn't even better for out-of-order exec around it.  Ice Lake improves that to 4 uops, and AMD runs it in 2 uops.  Scalar integer division inside loops sucks a lot, and is worth trying to do something about.  There are still a lot of Skylake-family CPUs around since Intel was stuck on that for a while especially on the desktop (unlike laptop tiger lake.)

Re: union type-punning: it is well-defined as a GNU extension to C++, and by MSVC.  So more realistically you should say "compilers other than MSVC and GCC/Clang/ICPX might generate incorrect code".  std::bit_cast<> is great because it has clean syntax and built-in checking of size compatibility, as well as being fully portable.

@PeterCordes Hm I see neither GCC nor Clang converting to float and back. I can imagine the compilers don't even consider doing that, but would there be anything against that in principle?

FP division is probably a good choice if round-to-nearest doesn't round up to a whole number in any cases where we need it to round down.  I'm pretty sure that won't happen when the dividend is a small number (64) and the divisors are whole numbers from 0 to 255; no way that could produce a quotient that was so close below a whole number that it rounded up.  Probably not even with AVX-512 BF16 or FP16, to get twice as many divisions per insn.  And yeah, CPU architects throw a lot of transistors at FP division to give it good throughput because many algorithms can't avoid it.

Should be true even for the general case of any u8 dividend and divisor.  C++ division by 0 is UB, so it's ok that the integer result would be 0x80000000 on x86 (Inf or NaN or other out-of-range conversion back to signed integer) or 0xffffffff (converted to unsigned with AVX-512). https://godbolt.org/z/osoG9Gjhb

Correction, AVX-512BF16 is only convert and dot-product.  Only AVX512 FP16 has a full set of ops (including VDIVPH ; PH is Packed Half.)

Maybe the best bet for vectorizing 64/x is packed 8-bit operations: compare against 64 and against 32, and I guess against 16.  Then the 0-15 case can be handled with a 4-bit parallel lookup table (x86 pshufb, ARM tbl.)  x86 AVX-512 vpermb can do a 32 or 64-entry LUT depending on vector width, so fewer compare results to merge with the LUT.  And I think ARM tbl can read multiple vectors so also do a 32-entry LUT.  Not widening to 32 or 64 means every instruction is working with 16 (or 32 or 64) values at once.

@Peter Cordes Your contribution is valuable to me, but my question is about the style of writing the code, not the specific solution to the math problem. I'm concerned with how readable this code is to unknown people, because I'm writing GNU code, and I don't know who is going to use, adapt, or maintain it. I am not trying to calculate multiple ⌊64/n⌋ values in parallel. Instead, I am using SWAR to speed up the calculation of a single ⌊64/n⌋ value. I inline this function in lots of other pieces of code, for example, to find how many n-bit values are packed into a uint64_t.

@wepajakeg: cool, then yeah branchy scalar code with both sides having few operations is probably good, especially on x86-64 where a large immediate is still a single instruction.  Other ways of packing multiple narrow integers into u64 include varint, where parallel SIMD decode is somewhat possible. (C++ how to speed up (with x86 SIMD) batch variable length integer encoding / decoding (runnable benchmark) and that whole Q&A.  Might or might not be relevant for your use-case.)
